# Sys arguments with while

Tags: python, python-3.x, sys

The lines in the files will be top to bottom (one under the other)

I have 2 ".txt" file like this :

```
#john.txt
hello     
my
name
is
John
#jack.txt
```

second one is like that:

```
hello
your
name
is
Jack
```

I will compare this texts line by line but the problem is when I write

"python john.txt jack.txt " on command line  sys.arg[1] and sys.argv[2]
will provide the lines and compare them . so sys.argv[1] must provide lines in file one by one but I will write"python john.txt jack.txt " only one time.
sample output:

```
python john.txt jack.txt
```

```
True
False
True
True
False
```

I say again. the sys.argv[1] and sys.argv[2] will provide file line by line and when the comparison ends. they will take next lines in files how can I do it ? 
I think it would done by using while loops but how ?

Comment: The lines in files will be top and bottom !! ( one under the other)

Comment: What would the expected output be?

Comment: if you call your program in that way (`python john.txt jack.txt`), then `sys.argv` will NOT contain the text files line by line, it will contain the strings `"john.txt"` and `"jack.txt"`. You will then have to `open()` those files in your code and use `getlines()` to load the contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will help to compare two files line by line and get expected results.

```
import sys

f1 = sys.argv[1]
f2 = sys.argv[2]

f1_data = open(f1, 'r')
f2_data = open(f2, 'r')

result = [True if f1_line == f2_line else False for f1_line, f2_line in zip(f1_data.readlines(), f2_data.readlines())]

# Result will be in list: [True, False, True, True, False]
print(result)
```